# How to create Analysis Services Multidimensional Project template in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: ssas, visual-studio-2019, multidimensional-cube

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-tutorial/lesson-1-1-creating-an-analysis-services-project?view=asallproducts-allversions). I use VS2019 Community and I've installed [Microsoft Analysis Services Project extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftAnalysisServicesModelingProjects). But when I try to create a new "Analysis Services Multidimensional and Data Mining Project" all I can see in the list of installed Analysis Services templates is "Analysis Services Tabular Project".

What else is missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I have not been able to figure out any way to get the multidimensional project types in there. For training I have taken a projectfile from Adventureworks github:
https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/tag/adventureworks-analysis-services

Opened it in visual studio 2019, cleaned it out and have it ready for personal use now. I know this is not a solid fix, but at least it might give something to work with for now.

Comment: Yes, @Joost, that's what I'm doing, so I'm not the only one. Thank you, that's comforting a bit)